# Better pattern for ORM in PHP and SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, orm

I'm just a newcomer in the world of PHP development.
I have a SQL Server 2005 database with stored procedures, and I would like to have PHP talking to it.
Since I'm just a newcomer, I'd like to have simple instructions to do so.

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials on how to call stored procedures from PHP.  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php  If you have specific questions, people here will be more then happy to help.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but I'm looking for SQL Server stored procedures.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-execute.php